# Réflexions sur la traduction de « Critical to safety (documents) » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, prépositions, faux-amis

Dans les [*Clés de la rédaction*](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/critique-adjectif.html) sur Termium on dit que "C’est à tort qu’on emploie le mot *critique* à la forme impersonnelle dans le sens d’« essentiel »". On n'étend pas la prescription à l'adjectif ou à l'attribut du sujet. C'est qu'on a des [syntagmes](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/critique) en science avec des sens rattachés à l'idée de crise, et aussi d'autres sens avec l'idée de conséquence, « déterminant » etc. Il n'est pas clair que l'adjectif puisse signifier « essentiel ».

Dans un contexte de traduction, je tombe sur « *[Critical](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/critical) to safety (documents)* » se rapportant à des documents qu'on qualifie ainsi, même parfois sans employer le mot « document » (comme un titre après lequel suivent des documents). Évidemment ce n'est pas le document en soi mais bien sa lecture et donc la connaissance de son contenu qui importe (pour des employés et leur employeur) ; il y a donc une espèce de téléscopage du sens.

Mais je note que le mot « essentiel » existe aussi en anglais (*essential*). J'hésite entre un emploi de « critique » que je ne suis pas certain de pouvoir étayer, et une emploi d' « essentiel » qui ne me semble pas d'un assez haut degré sans adverbe ou un autre adjectif. Incidemment je me demande si je préfère la préposition *à* ou *pour*.

- Peut-on employer « critique » dans un tel cas ou faudrait-il plutôt
  complètement reformuler, voire parler de « lecture » : pourquoi ?
- Quels sont d'autres choix d'adjectifs usuels dans un tel contexte, et recherche-t-on un plus haut
  degré en ajoutant un adverbe/adjectif et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3):

[La source indiquée](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/critique-adjectif.html) (site du gouvernement du Canada) différe des [sens recensés](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/critique) par le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/dictionnaires/modernes/).

Dans le cas d'un document, on peut utiliser l'adjectif **crucial**. Pour une problématique particulière, "*critique*" convient parfaitement

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, j'oublierais les dictionnaires, et j'essaierais de voir quel est le *but* de la communication ici. Si l'enjeu de ces informations liées à la sécurité n'est pas trop important, tu pourrais utiliser:

> Informations de sécurité importantes/essentielles

Un cran au-dessus, si le message doit bien passer et qu'il y a des risques significatifs si ce document n'est pas lu, tu pourrais dire:

> Informations cruciales/capitales pour la sécurité

Encore un cran au-dessus, pour suggérer que c'est une question de vie ou de mort (si c'est bien le cas):

> Informations vitales de sécurité (voire avec **vitales** en gras)

Mais quitte à me répéter, je choisirais la "traduction" en fonction du but visé, plutôt qu'en fonction d'une exactitude supposée du mot dans une référence. Tous les dictionnaires du monde n'ont aucune importance s'il faut être sûr que l'interlocuteur comprend bien et prend la bonne action en conséquence. Il vaut mieux un mot efficace plutôt qu'un mot correct.